# Using OAuth or API key AuthN/Z in dotnetcore webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a dotnetcore webapi endpoint and I currently have OAUth with a server-side redeemed access token to get the JWT, and an AUTH cookie is returned to the client.
In my program.cs, I don't do anything special, I just have

```
builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // If an authentication cookie is present, use it to get authentication information
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // If authentication is required, and no cookie is present, use OAUTH
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyOAUTHProvider";
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/accessdenied";
        })
        .AddOAuth(
            "MyOAUTHProvider",
            (OAuthOptions options) =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint += context =>
                {
                    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(context.RedirectUri)
                    {
                        Scheme = "https",
                        Port = -1
                    };
                    context.RedirectUri = uriBuilder.ToString();
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                };

                OAuthHelper.Process(options, myOAuthConfig);
            }
        );

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    });
```

and my OAuthHelper.Process is just the standard fare

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth;
using WebApp.Config;

namespace WebApp.Utils;

public static class OAuthHelper
{
    public static Action<OAuthOptions, MyOAUTHProviderConfig> Process = (
        OAuthOptions options,
        MyOAUTHProviderConfig myOAUTHProviderConfig
    ) =>
    {
        // Oauth authentication middleware is second

        var myOAUTHProviderDomain = myOAUTHProviderConfig.AuthBaseUri;

        // When a user needs to sign in, they will be redirected to the authorize endpoint
        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"{myOAUTHProviderDomain}/authorize";

        // MyOAUTHProvider's OAuth server is OpenID compliant, so request the standard openid
        // scopes when redirecting to the authorization endpoint
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("authz");

        // After the user signs in, an authorization code will be sent to a callback
        // in this app. The OAuth middleware will intercept it
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString(myOAUTHProviderConfig.AuthRedirectUri);

        // The OAuth middleware will send the ClientId, ClientSecret, and the
        // authorization code to the token endpoint, and get an access token in return

        options.ClientId = myOAUTHProviderConfig.AuthClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = myOAUTHProviderConfig.AuthClientSecret;
        options.TokenEndpoint = $"{myOAUTHProviderDomain}/token";

        // Below we call the userinfo endpoint to get information about the user
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = $"{myOAUTHProviderDomain}/userinfo";

        // Describe how to map the user info we receive to user claims
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                // Get user info from the userinfo endpoint and use it to populate user claims
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
                    HttpMethod.Get,
                    context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint
                );
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Bearer",
                    context.AccessToken
                );
                var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(
                    request,
                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                    context.HttpContext.RequestAborted
                );
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(responseContent);

                context.RunClaimActions(user);
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Now, what I would like to do, is, if a request contains a header like 'X-API-Key' with an API key, to route the request away from the OAuth pipeline, but rather use the API Key to authenticate the user.

Does anyone have any samples for this, I am having trouble wrapping my mind around it - I think I can define middleware to check the request for an `X-API-Key` header

```cs
public class AuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();

        if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("ApiKey"))
        {
            // Use ApiKey logic
        /* HERE is the crux of the question?*/            
        /* How do I bypass OAUTH if the APIKey is determined to be valid*/
        }
        
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();
    // ... other middlewares
}
```

In `Program.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthActionFilter());
    });
}
```

I'm not sure how to bypass OAuth if the API Key is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a return statement in the if block to bypass the next middleware. So something like this.

```
  if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("ApiKey"))
    {
     //// Bypass all subsequent middleware and return immediately
    return;
    }
    //otherwise continue with the oauth authentication
    await _next(context);
```

Comment: And here I was scratching my head - Thanks!